# Insert harcoded and selected values into table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to insert a row into settings table.
for columns A,B I need to hardcode their value and for column C I need it equal to a user id selected from the user table

```
INSERT INTO settings (A, B, user_id)
SELECT 'style', 1, users.id
FROM users;
```

this query returns an error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
```

Comment: That is valid SQL: https://rextester.com/XWEA66303 - Which DBMS product are you using? And how (and where) are you running that query?

Comment: psql,using postico as GUI running the query in the query

Comment: Then it's probably that "postico" GUI that messes with your (valid) query.